# Strange issue with values a while loop?

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I am working on a program that prints out steps and running into a strange problem with a while loop. For some reason the loop starts at 1 instead of 0 and I can't pinpoint why it is exactly.

Current Output:

```
Array Rows: 5
Array Columns: 5
_ _ _ _ _ 
X _ _ _ _ 
X X _ _ _ 
X X X _ _ 
X X X X _
```

Desired Output:

```
Array Rows: 5
Array Columns: 5
X _ _ _ _ 
X X _ _ _ 
X X X _ _ 
X X X X _ 
X X X X X
```

Code For Function:

```
if(rows == columns):
        x = 0
        while(x < rows):
            y = 0
            while(y < x):
                array[x][y] = "X"
                y += 1
            x += 1
```

Note: The rows and columns are user inputs from the main program to specify how large the 2D list should be.

Here is the output with a debugging print showing the issue:

```
Array Rows: 5
Array Columns: 5
1
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
_ _ _ _ _ 
X _ _ _ _ 
X X _ _ _ 
X X X _ _ 
X X X X _
```

Note: The change in this output is a print statement of "x" in the 2nd nested while loop.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've spent a ton of time trying to figure out what is wrong without any luck :/

Comment: Can you show the complete code? Rows, columns, array declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be 0 X's in row 0, 1 X in row 1, etc. with your current code.  That's because on row 0, the inner `while` loop iterates 0 times, because the initial test `x < y` fails before the loop starts.  `0` is not less than `0`.

Perhaps you want `y <= x` in your inner `while` loop?

Comment: Ah this was the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to test whether `y <= x`, as on the diagonal, your row number will be *equal* to your column number.

```
if rows == columns:
    x = 0
    while x < rows:
        y = 0
        while y <= x:
            array[x][y] = "X"
            y += 1
        x += 1
```

Just a hint: you could use a `for` loop to make this a bit simpler:

```
if rows == columns:
    for x in range(0, rows):
        for y in range(0, x + 1):
            array[x][y] = "X"
```